# alembic doesn't detect relationship table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, alembic

I've defined some models with some association tables for m2m relationships:

```
from itsdangerous import TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer
from passlib.hash import bcrypt
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

import app 
from app import db

Base = declarative_base()

class UserGroupRelationship(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'users_groups'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('groups.id'), primary_key=True)

class FriendRelationship(Base):
    __tablename__ = u'users_friends'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_left = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_right = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)


class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = u'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120))
    # ...
    last_login = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    friends = db.relationship(FriendRelationship,
            primaryjoin=id==FriendRelationship.user_left,
            backref='friends', lazy='dynamic')
    friends_with = db.relationship(FriendRelationship,
            primaryjoin=id==FriendRelationship.user_right,
            backref='friends_with', lazy='dynamic')


class Group(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = u'groups'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    users = db.relationship(UserGroupRelationship,
            primaryjoin=id==UserGroupRelationship.group_id,
            backref='groups', lazy='dynamic')


class Device(db.Model):
    ''' devices linked to users '''

    __tablename__ = u'devices'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    uuid = db.Column(db.String(50))
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('groups.id'))
```

running `alembic revision --autogenerate` does generate table for classes inheriting from `db.Model` but not for the tables used for my m2m relationships.

```
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected added table u'groups'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected added table u'users'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected added table u'devices'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate] Detected added table u'question'
  Generating /Users/rxdazn/w/xxx/xxx-
  yyy/migrations/versions/4e47aa7f3050_.py...done
```

My `alembic.ini` and `env.py` files are the default ones. I simply import my models init my project's `__init__.py`

any idea of what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Why do you inherit the association tables from `Base` while your models inherit from `db.Model`? They are all models, right?

Comment: @Miguel I thought relationships were something different than simple models. I mean I thought they shouldn't be models. Inheriting from `db.Model` seems to have solved my problem.  
Could you please create post it as answer so I can mark my question as solved? Thanks (and thanks for your blog posts too!).

Comment: There are two patterns for many-to-many relationships. The [basic one](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many) uses a `Table` object for the association table. The [advanced one](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#association-object) uses models, and has the advantage that you can store additional columns in the association table. You seem to be using the advanced one, but if you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy then all your models should inherit from `db.Model`, you should not go directly to SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I see, inheriting from db.Model is like using Django's M2M with a `through` attribute. I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy indeed.

Comment: Any improvement on the issue if you change your tables to inherit from `db.Model`?

Comment: Yes it did solve the issue, see this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906544/alembic-doesnt-detect-relationship-table?noredirect=1#comment33201915_21906544
Create an answer so I can mark it as solved!

Answer (score 7):

*(Miguel answered this in the comments. I'll delete this answer if he posts it and someone pokes me in a comment. I only posted it so it could be marked as an answer, as I had the same problem and almost left the page before reading the comments.)*

Don't inherit the association tables from `Base`. All models should inherit from `db.Model`, like this:

```
class FriendRelationship(db.Model):
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906544/alembic-doesnt-detect-relationship-table#comment33211385_21906544) is why:

> There are two patterns for many-to-many relationships. The basic one
>   uses a Table object for the association table. The advanced one uses
>   models, and has the advantage that you can store additional columns in
>   the association table. You seem to be using the advanced one, but if
>   you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy then all your models should inherit
>   from db.Model. You should not go directly to SQLAlchemy.